# How to Remove Google Add when I add Google Custom Search Eng

Tags: seo, google-search-api, google-search-platform

I have query related to  Google Custom Search Eng

I have added Google Custom Search Eng to my website..when i search for things its display result well.But its also comes with Some add..

I dont wana this Google add ! (I dont go with payment option )

Let me know if is there any way !

please see the bellow image! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFxTb.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Varma Amit For not showing Ads just go to **Business** option in left menu and select do not show ad option.Refer the below image[image]

Hope you get your answer.